# every figure is placed on a different page and alone. how I can fix that and put 2 or 3 figures on the same page

Tags: floats, positioning

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
      \includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{1.jpg}
  \caption{Sum-rates with respect to signal to noise ratio}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
      \includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{2.jpg}
  \caption{Sum-rates with respect to signal to noise ratio}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: If you provide no example it is impossible to say why latex placed the figures as it did (you can place them all in the same `figure` environment if they must stay together). Note that `\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{2.jpg}` is necessarily too large and will generate warnings and will stick in to the right margin and not be centred.

Comment: How I can put the figure in the center.

Comment: use `\textwidth` not `1.1\textwidth`

Comment: The figure in the center, but I still had the same problem, each figure on different page

Comment: as I said we can not help with that if you provide no test file.  Other than as I suggest above delete the three middle lines `\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering`  so the two figures always float together

Comment: with the default settings latex only makes a float page (a page with just floats) if half the page is full so it will only make two consecutive float pages if the two figures are each more than half of \textheight and so would not fit on the same page.

Comment: How tall are the images in the jpeg files?